# Numpy array operation precision with very small values

Tags: python, numpy, precision

I've got some trouble with the precision of my array operations. I'm doing alot of array calculations where some cells of the array have to be left out, done either by masking or, in this case, by assigning very small values neary `np.finfo(float).tiny` to the array cells to leave out.
But during array operations this causes an error of around `1e-14` which is quite near to machine epsilon. But still I don't know where the error is coming from and how to avoid it. Since I perform these operations several million times, the errors stack up to a total error of around 2-3%.
Here is my minimum working example:

```
arr = np.arange(20).astype(float)
arr[0] = 1e-290
t1 = np.random.rand(20) * 100
t2 = np.random.rand(20) * 100
a = (arr * (t1 - t2)).sum()
b = (arr * (t1 - t2))[1:].sum()
d = (arr * (t1 - t2))[0].sum()
c = b - a
print(c)
# Out[99]: 4.5474735088646412e-13
```

To avoid this problem, I tried to mask `arr`:

```
arr_mask = np.ma.masked_where(arr < 1e-200, arr)
a_mask = (arr_mask * (t1 - t2)).sum()
b_mask = (arr_mask * (t1 - t2))[1:].sum()
c_mask = b_mask - a_mask
print(c_mask)
# Out[118]: 4.5474735088646412e-13
```

Why is the difference, `c` so many magnitudes bigger than `d`, which should be the difference? I guess some machine epsilon problem from assigning such a small value to the array in the first place? But still `np.finfo(float).eps` with `2.2204460492503131e-16` is around a 1000 times smaller than `c`.
How can I avoid this? Setting the elements to zero won't work, since I have lots of divisions. In this case I can't use masking to several reasons. BUT the position of the cells which have to be left out does NEVER change. So can I somehow assign a "safe" value to these cells to leave them out while altering the result of the total array operations?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you using a tiny number to mask with? I'd use NaN instead. Numpy has a number of NaN-ignoring primitives (e.g. `nansum`) that are useful if you use NaN to mark bad data.

Comment: `nansum` is about 3 times slower than `sum` and in my case this matters. Besides that my array operations are complicated and I didn't find a possibility to implement all of them with NaNs.

Comment: Have you tried boolean masking? I.e., `arr[boolean_mask]`? It is probably your best bet.

Comment: Another option is to use `math.fsum()` on your arrays insead of numpy's sum. Just do some timing tests.

Comment: @AGNGazer yeah, I tried both. But boolean masking does not work since I have alot of different operations in one line which would otherwise require much more multiplication/division operations and all these operations would need different boolean masks. `math.fsum` is about 12 times slower than `np.sum`.

Comment: Yeah, I just checked this myself - all are quite slow. Summation of masked arrays was "only" 3x slower than original numpy summation. It is the price that you will have to pay if you need that kind of accuracy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The granularity of a given float type is not fixed but depends on the size of the value you are starting from. I encourage you to play with the `numpy.nextafter` function:

```
a = 1.5
>>> np.nextafter(a, -1)
1.4999999999999998
>>> a - np.nextafter(a, -1)
2.220446049250313e-16
>>> a = 1e20
>>> np.nextafter(a, -1)
9.999999999999998e+19
>>> a - np.nextafter(a, -1)
16384.0
```

This shows that the smallest positive difference you can obtain by subtracting some fp number from `a` depends on the how large `a` is.

You should now be able to work out what happens in your example

Comment: What I am running into is the following: Let's introduce `v = arr * (t1 - t2)` and also `w = v.copy(); w[0] = 0`. Then do the following: 1) `v.sum()-w.sum()` will give 0.0 while `w.sum()-w[1:].sum()` is not zero (even though the first element of `w` is *exactly* zero!

Comment: @AGNGazer That may be due to pairwise summation. v and w are the same length, so their elements can be expected to be summed in the same order under the pairwise summation algorithm. Since v[0] is so small it will likely behave like zero when summed, so the sums should indeed be exactly equal. By contrast w and w[1:] will be summed in a different order and that will make the difference.

Comment: Thanks Paul Panzer, that helps alot! So that means that all values in my float array should be in the same range of order of magnitudes? So what would you suggest to solve my problem? Set cells to leave out to something like `1e-30`? I need a quite big security factor of at least `1e10` to "real" numbers which can go down to `1e-10` easily...

Comment: @Scotty1- I'm not aware of a truly satisfactory solution to your problem. As you're saying nan is to slow for you but your invalids are in fixed position you could do the  bookkeeping on them separately and just ignore their values. That would however mean that you have to fill them with neutrals (e,g, 0 for sum, 1 for prod etc) whenever you are doing a reduce operation.

Comment: @PaulPanzer ok, thanks alot anyways! Unluckily this won't work since many of my arrays are used in sums, products and divisions simultaneously. Changing the value of the cells to leave out `1e-20` interestingly does not change the error my program code produces, while in my minimum working example it resolves the problem...